# Werewolf Novel about a secret agent werewolf Multilingual

Tags: story-identification, novel, werewolf

I read a werewolf novel once about a "secret agent" werewolf. I remember he was multilingual and at some point in the novel he was masquerading as an Italian (Calabrese) and I remember he got snippy with someone because they were trying to tell him how a Calabrese accent was different from standard Italian and he was like "I *know* it sounds like that..." I can't remember the author or anything else about the book.  At some point I lost it and I am trying to find it again.  I know this isn't much to go on but maybe someone here might recognize it.

Comment: Approximately when did you read this?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of possibilities:

- *[The Wolf's Hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf%27s_Hour)* (1989) - Features a British agent dropped into France to get information that might impact Operation Overlord with his secret advantage being that he's a werewolf.
- *[Wolf Mark](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11345765-wolf-mark)* (2011) - A Young Adult book featuring the child of a black ops infiltrator who is transforming into a werewolf.

Neither mentions speaking Italian, let alone Calabrese, but I figure it's a start for you. Do either of those sound familiar?